# Use shortlink as permalink

Tags: permalinks, shortlink

I'm using Url shortener plugin with bit.ly API.
When I use the bit.ly url, it's redirecting to my Wordpress permalink. How Can I use the bit.ly all the time ?
I want the bit.ly url become the permalink or my posts.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Buy Bit.ly. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

> bit.ly Offers URL redirection service with real-time link tracking.

Sorry, I do not think it's possible and even if it was I do not understand why you need it.

Comment: to get statistic in any time. Because facebook take your real adress

Comment: I mean if you share your bit.ly facebook will share your real adresse so it wont be tracked with stats

Comment: URL shortener are meant to make URL trackable. That's not normal if you can't see it.

Comment: @user1708580 if Facebook chooses to resolve shortened link there is nothing you can do to prevent it